# Leaflet: don't fire a click event function on double-click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a question concerning clicks on a map in Leaflet. If I click on the map I want to set a marker there, but if I double-click on the map, I just want to zoom in without setting a marker. So I have the following code:

```
var map = L.map(attrs.id, {
            center: [scope.lat, scope.lng],
            zoom: 14
        });
var marker = L.marker([scope.lat, scope.lng],{draggable: true});
map.on('click', function(event){
            marker.setLatLng(event.latlng);
            marker.addTo(map);
        });
```

The problem now is, when I double-click on the map, the click event is also fired and I would like to remove that behavior. How can I achieve that?

Comment: please review [MDN Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), you might just find the event you are after ;)

Comment: I've never worked with leaflet, so I don't know if it supports this already, but the technique you might be looking for is called [debouncing](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).  In essence, delay placing the marker, and if another click event happens during this time, zoom in.

Comment: @ScottKaye: Thanks for your answer - I used a delay, as you suggested.

Comment: Please do not post a solution as an edit to the **question**. You can post an **answer** to your own questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a way to do that, but I am still not sure if there is a better way to do it.

```
var map = L.map(attrs.id, {
        center: [scope.lat, scope.lng],
        zoom: 14
    });
map.clicked = 0;                                                                      
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([scope.lat, scope.lng],{draggable: true});
map.on('click', function(event){
    map.clicked = map.clicked + 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(map.clicked == 1){
            marker.setLatLng(event.latlng);
            marker.addTo(map);                
            map.clicked = 0;
        }
     }, 300);
});
map.on('dblclick', function(event){
    map.clicked = 0;
    map.zoomIn();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem of 2 x unwanted `click` events firing when listening for `dblclick`.

**Note:** I wanted single and double clicks on the same element to perform different actions.

I adapted this approach to my Leaflet map, which is not bulletproof but eliminates 99% of the conflicts:

```
var timer = 0;
var delay = 200;
var prevent = false;

$("#target")
  .on("click", function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (!prevent) {
        doClickAction();
      }
      prevent = false;
    }, delay);
  })
  .on("dblclick", function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    prevent = true;
    doDoubleClickAction();
  });
```

Credit: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/bind-different-events-to-click-and-double-click/)

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/HfBtz)

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue on recent (Leaflet 1.4) versions.

An alternative approach I used that:

- legitimate usage of `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`
- without adding random props to the map object
- no [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
  if (_dblClickTimer !== null) {
    return;
  }
  _dblClickTimer = setTimeout(() => {

    // Real 'click' event handler here

    _dblClickTimer = null;
  }, 200);
})
.on("dblclick", function() {
  clearTimeout(_dblClickTimer);
  _dblClickTimer = null;

  // Real 'dblclick' handler here (if any). Do not add anything to just have the default zoom behavior
});
```

Note that the 200 ms delay must be tested. On my environment, using a value like 100 was not enough as the double-click event is triggered with a delay.

Comment: Hi @Keul. I just posted a question, dealing with the correct implementation of what you're describing in R. Ideally, I'd like a single-click to launch the flyToBounds() function, and the double-click to still just zoom. Not sure how to post the link to the question here, but it's on my profile. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use 500ms which is the default OS dbclick timespan