# wkWebview Navigator Hangs on a simple page on IOS13

Tags: codenameone

Since I updated to IOS13 our App hangs, the page and de Menu don't work, on IOS12 works fine.

I attach a simple code to try, simple press some times for example on zoom in/out and alternate with click on map, and the App hangs.

```
                Form hi = new Form("form2");

                Toolbar tb = hi.getToolbar();
                Image icon = theme.getImage("icon.png"); 
                Container topBar = BorderLayout.east(new Label(icon));
                topBar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("Cool App Tagline...", "SidemenuTagline")); 
                topBar.setUIID("SideCommand");
                tb.addComponentToSideMenu(topBar);

                tb.addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e -> {}); 

                hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                
                BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();
                browserComponent.setURL("https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html");

                hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browserComponent);
                hi.show();
```

Comment: `hi` should have a border layout and the browser component should be in the center. Also forceRevalidate() isn't needed. It's just slow.

Comment: I corrected it, still fails on IOS13, Clicking on the map some times and on the zoom controls makes the app dont respond, and the menu dont work again. Updated de Code. On a nativa webBrowser works fine on IOS12 and IOS13.

Comment: Does this apply for every page e.g. Google.com etc? Is it possible that specific page is causing a problem?

Comment: Hi Shai, Does only apply to this page on the codenameone webBrowser component, that page on native web browser (tested son some browser and devices) works fine. On IOS 12 works fine, it starts to fail on update IOS to 13.

Comment: Try using this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html
To look at the device native logs. Is something printed there when running this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the leaflet.js, in this commit https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/6855/files/862d3f600ce0f40795149a32bf980ff6000bf132 makes the library 1.6.0 hangs on codenameOne and IOS13.

The solution for me, was use the oficial 1.5.1 library (http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.5.1/leaflet.zip) and make a function to emulate an doubleclick, based on this post: [leaflet: don't fire click event function on doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035896/leaflet-dont-fire-click-event-function-on-doubleclick)

This is part of code:

```
        // Create a Global variable
        var clicked = 0;

        //on map declaration disable tap and doubleClickZomm
        mapid = new L.map("mapid",{ attributionControl: false, zoomControl: false, doubleClickZoom: false, tap : false});

        // Map click event                  
        mapid.on('click', function(e) {
            // Calling the new function
            controlClick(); 
        });
                
        // Map DoubleClick event                    
        mapid.on('dblclick', function(e) {
            // Calling the new function
            controlClick();    
        });

        /*
        *  Declare an Emmulated doubleClickZoom function
        */
        function controlClick(){
            clicked = clicked +1;
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(clicked > 0){
                    clicked = 0;
                }
             }, 500);
            if (clicked > 1 ){
                mapid.zoomIn();
                clicked = 0;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: I would like to add a consideration to this kind of problems: in the case of iOS, the rendering of pages done by Safari is different from the one done by WKWebView (used by BrowserComponent).  This is a problem that goes beyond Codename One and sometimes creates incompatibilities such that what works well with Safari will never work in any native app. An example is the support for the WebRTC standard, which in Safari is complete, in WKWebView is often unusable. This is the same reason why, in iOS, all browsers other than Safari will always be inferior to Safari, because they use WKWebView.

Comment: Agree Francesco. I went crazy to fix the problem.Thanks